# Removing Installed App in 'Ubuntu Software' doesnt work?

Tags: uninstall

In Ubuntu software I am trying to remove all the apps I dont want. like browser and various card games etc etc.

Issue is I click remove, it removed them, then the list refreshes and they are back?

Any idea how I can decullter and remove these apps?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The first time you hit Remove, it's removed. It's just some strange behavior in Ubuntu Software that causes it to show up again in the list as still installed. If you want to be sure the application is gone, you can check it with the Synaptic package manager.

Comment: Ah ok thats very confusing then as to what is and isnt installed! Is there a way i can use Synaptic to view it more clearly rather than the level of detail it gives?

Comment: I'm not aware of other view options for synaptic. You could also install the older Ubuntu Software Center, which some have found preferable to the newer Gnome version that was adopted for 16.04. Again, you could install the Classic Menu Indicator, which I use. It provides a drop down menu of all installed software packages.

Comment: Cheers ill give it a go!

Comment: Ubuntu Software is, to put it bluntly, extremely buggy. I've seen removed items in the Installed tab, items listed twice, and straight-up crashes. Avoid interacting with that app at all costs and instead use CLI or Synaptic Package Manager.